# Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) occured in console

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, video-streaming, video-processing, cross-origin-read-blocking

I am trying to add a video conferencing component to my react js frontend. Video conferencing URL domain is already working in browser. but it is showing [CORB] error when i add that in react component.I tried the following code.

```
class ResponsivePlayer extends Component {
    render () {
      return (
        <div className='player-wrapper'>
          <ReactPlayer
            className='react-player'
            url='<video conferencing url>'

          />
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
export default ResponsivePlayer;
```

the error on my console shows like this:-

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response *https://""* with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
```

Can anyone give a solution?